# Third @media max-width not working in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

so im trying to build out a website for different screen sizes. now ive included a card section into this that is included into my website. now when my screen is at full size eg >1300px in width it should be 5 wide now when it gets to 1300px wide i dont want it to change but when it gets to 1024px wide i wanted it to drop down to 3 wide which it does however as soon as i get to the 614px wide section i want it to activate and change the amounnt of displays per row to two rather than the 3 when the screen size is greater than 614px wide.

[5 wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiR5O.jpg)
so this is how i wanted it to look when the screen was > 1024px wide which it does

[3 wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue7UM.jpg)
once i get to < 1024px wide it goes to 3 wide just fine

[should be 2 wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccTF7.png)
But as soon as i go past that 614px wide mark the @media screen and (max-width: 614px) dosent kick in for some reason
however if i change it to @media screen and (min-width: 614px) the media changes do affect it but it stops the rest of the media effects from working ive even tried switching around other media effects min and max values nothing i seem to do can get them to work all indivually

```css
.third-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 1420px;
    margin: 40px; 
    padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;

}


.column2 {
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    

}

.card {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) ;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 330px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
    margin: 2px 2px;
}


.card img {
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.card h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #232323;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px
    

}
.card p{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #C49954;
}
.card a{
    border: 20px #C49954;
    padding: 2px;
}
.card hr{
    border: 2px solid #C49954;
    width: 50%;
    transition: ease 0.5s;

}
.card:hover hr{
    border: 2px solid #C49954;
    width: 75%;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.card:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.card:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: ease 0.5s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.card:hover h2{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.card:hover p{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.card:hover a{
    transform: scale(1.03);
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px){
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 615px){

    }
    .column2{
        width: calc(33% - 60px);
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .card{
        width: calc(100% - 15px);
        margin: 2px 2px;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 614px)
{
/*index.html styling*/

        
    }
    .column2{
        width: calc(50% - 60px);
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .card{
        width: calc(100% - 15px);
        margin: 2px 2px;
    }

  }
```

```html
<div class="third-main">
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/201/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Robotic Mowers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p> 

        </div>
 
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/202/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Commerical Mowers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p> 

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/203/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Residential Mowers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/204/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Power Equipment</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/206/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Accessories & Saftey Gear</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/208/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Cargo Trailers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/209/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Livestock Trailers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/210/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Dump Trailers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/211/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Utility & Landscape Trailers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/212/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Deckover Trailers</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card" id="card3">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/213/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Equipment Rentals</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card" id="card3">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/214/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>New Heavy Equipment</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card" id="card3">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/215/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Used Heavy Equipment</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column2">
        <div class="card" id="card3">
          <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/216/200">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <h2>Attachments</h2>
          <br>
          <p>Learn More</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

I have tried just about everything on stack and am just at a loss for where to go with this any help would be apreciated if you want the full css file i can paste it here or anything else from my files thats referenced i can include i just have a feeling that its with the @media querys itself.

Comment: What does ‘doesn’t work’ mean? What is going wrong? And where are the settings for everything else, E.g. wider viewports?

Comment: By dosent work i mean that @media 614px dosent kick in when below 614px

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ive read through that haworth dosent really explain why the first and second @media work just fine but the third dosent work unless you change the value to a min value. maybe im wrong tho im new to this website stuff

Comment: What @AHaworth is saying is that we need more information to be able to help you. The code you have included in your question is not sufficient. Please edit your question to include a description of your expected result, your actual result, and enough HTML and CSS so that we can replicate your result.

Comment: ok i gotcha will do that rq

Comment: ok ive added a ton more info and added the html and such let me know if you need anything else ive also talked about what i am expecting and what im receiving with images included @Brett Donald

Comment: Thank you for including a runnable snippet. You have however now included a typo, a spurious closing bracket immediately after the comment in the last media query. The media query kicks in if you remove that. However, although it shrinks the images it still has large font size. I suggest you work on that and that we close this question.

Comment: @AHaworth actually both media queries contain a stray closing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your desired layout the best solution is a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), with media queries controlling the number of columns.

When writing stylesheets, best practice is to follow a mobile-first approach. Start with the mobile styles, then add media queries where necessary to specify styles for wider screens, in *increasing order of width*.

```css
body {
  background: #888;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  }
}

.d1>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) ;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #232323;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #C49954;
}

a {
  border: 20px #C49954;
  padding: 2px;
}

hr {
  border: 2px solid #C49954;
  width: 50%;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}

.d1>div:hover hr {
  border: 2px solid #C49954;
  width: 75%;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.d1>div:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.d1>div:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.d1>div:hover h2 {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.d1>div:hover p {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.d1>div:hover a {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: ease 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/201/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Robotic Mowers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/202/200/300">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Commerical Mowers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/203/300/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Residential Mowers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/204/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Power Equipment</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/206/200/300">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Accessories &amp; Saftey Gear</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/208/300/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Cargo Trailers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/209/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Livestock Trailers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/210/200/300">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Dump Trailers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/211/300/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Utility &amp; Landscape Trailers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/212/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Deckover Trailers</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/213/200/300">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Equipment Rentals</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/214/300/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>New Heavy Equipment</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/215/200">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Used Heavy Equipment</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/216/200/300">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h2>Attachments</h2>
    <p>Learn More</p>
  </div>
      
</div>
```

After running this snippet, make sure to use the **full page** link to test the responsive behaviour.

Comment: thanks for your input thats mostly solved the problem but does that mean i have to go through and restyle my whole website virtullay from the ground up?

Comment: I only said that writing your styles mobile-first was best practice. Other arrangements can work too. If you are mostly happy with the structure of your style sheet, then don't start from scratch, just change the bits relating to the layout of these cards.

Comment: i know its a late reply took a couple days off. thanks for your help! i apreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

only thing that i can see is that you have to ensure that the styles defined in each of these media queries don't conflict with each other, as the ranges overlap (for example, a device with a width of 614px would match both the second and third media queries). Try changing to 615px in the 2nd.

Comment: yeah unfortunatly ive tried this still wont switch to the last @media when below that screen width